Ошибка при создании проекта react js
скачал react js, пытаюсь создать проект, выдает ошибку
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\artem\Desktop\Projects\netgenius.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


added 1320 packages in 47s

265 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Git repo not initialized Error: Command failed: git --version
    at genericNodeError (node:internal/errors:983:15)
    at wrappedFn (node:internal/errors:537:14)
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:882:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:954:15)
    at tryGitInit (C:\Users\artem\Desktop\Projects\netgenius\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:46:5)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\artem\Desktop\Projects\netgenius\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:276:7)
    at [eval]:3:14
    at runScriptInThisContext (node:internal/vm:209:10)
    at node:internal/process/execution:118:14
    at [eval]-wrapper:6:24 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 25812,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: netgenius@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\artem\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-18T15_08_06_869Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\artem\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-18T15_08_06_869Z-debug-0.log

npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0 failed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages

Попробуйте сделать поочередно, не спеша:

Установите Node.js и npm.
Перейдите в папку вашего проекта cd my-project.
Инициализируйте npm init -y.
Установите React npm install -g create-react-app.
Создайте приложение npx create-react-app . - точка указывает текущую папку.
Запустите npm start.

P.s. Еще бывает, что React ругается на папку, названную большими буквами, поэтому старайтесь называть папки маленькими буквами.
